# datetime Regular Expressions pattern to match yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss format

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to create regex pattern in javascript to validate datetime format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

```
/([0-2][0-9]{3})\-([0-1][0-9])\-([0-3][0-9]) ([0-5][0-9])\:([0-5][0-9])\:([0-5][0-9])(([\-\+]([0-1][0-9])\:00))/
```

here is an example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLL3h9ky/)

but its not working when i test it against this date time 2017-08-31 01:22:34
can anybody help me to know whats wrong in my pattern
Thank you

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - but maybe google first?

Comment: Although its a nice experiment to play with for regEx, doing date parsing is way better & more accurate if you use a heavily tested library to do this for you.  moment.js -> https://momentjs.com/  springs to mind.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the pattern currently requires, rather than makes optional, the timezone modifier, which isn't present in the example date you gave.

Change the last part to:

```
( ([\-\+]([0-1][0-9])\:00))?
```

Also:

- your hours sub-group is matching 0-59 rather than 0-23.
- you're escaping a number of things you don't need to, e.g. `:` and `-`
- the pattern allows for invalid dates e.g. 39 as a day.

Revision:

```
/^([0-2][0-9]{3})\-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])\:([0-5][0-9])( ([\-\+]([0-1][0-9])\:00))?$/
```

Note this will not account for invlaid dates in certain months e.g. 30th February. That means either making the pattern more complicated or using something better suited than REGEX for date validation.

Comment: @ahmdabos  It wasn't me either, but one reason might be what @mplugjam said,. `Please click the <> and create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`.  It would have been very easy for you to do this, and would have made it much easier for SO members to help.

Comment: this still has issue when i test 2017-08-31 01:22:34aaaa (plus characters to the end of the time) its passed but that wrong it should not pass the test

Comment: @Utkanos: This was very helpful and was saving tons of time. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the last part which should be optional `(([\-\+]([0-1][0-9])\:00))?`

Here is a demo

```js
var a = /([0-2][0-9]{3})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) ([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(([\-\+]([0-1][0-9])\:00))?/;

console.log('2017-08-31 01:22:34'.match(a))
```

BTW, you don't have to escape `:`. `-` should be escaped only when used inside brackets `[]`

Answer (score 0):

In java, we can use like below and also you can take this pattern for javascript

```
private static Pattern DATE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*?\[0-9\]{4}-(0\[1-9\]|1\[0-2\])-(0\[1-9\]|\[1-2\]\[0-9\]|3\[0-1\]) (2\[0-3\]|\[01\]\[0-9\]):\[0-5\]\[0-9\]:\[0-5\]\[0-9\]");

public void test() {
    if(!DATE_PATTERN.matcher(line.trim()).matches()) {
        //code here
    }
}
```

[image]

If you want to check only date then remove `*?` from the pattern